# use a key array to do math on another array

Tags: php

I have two arrays one is :

```
[2] => H
[3] => O
```

and another array which is

```
[0] => H4
[1] =>  O
[2] =>  H2O
```

what I want is this

```
[0] => 2H4        //H key is 2 in the first array I want 2 to show beside the H
[1] =>  3O        //O key is 3 in the first array I want 3 to show beside the O
[2] =>  6H2O     //This one contains two elements I want the multiple of the keys (2x3) before the compound
```

How do you do that in PHP? I have been working on this for hours and still have no idea on how to reach what I want. Tips and methods are welcomed!

Comment: Please try something...you look like a kind of guy that can...
Use : 
strpos() - Find the letter you want, 
foreach($array as $key=>value) - You can get the 2 and 3 and H and O;
$a.$b - concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$array1=array(2=>'H',3=>'O');
$array2=array(0=>'H4',1=>'O',2=>'H2O');
$array3=array();
foreach ($array2 as $value1) {
    $result=array_product(array_flip(array_intersect($array1,str_split($value1))));
    $array3[]=$result==1?''.$value1:$result.$value1;
}
var_dump($array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaking suspicion you aren't painting the full picture here, but this will do exactly what you asked for...

```
$array1  = array(
  2 => 'H',
  3 => 'O'
);
$array2 = array('H4','O','H2O');

$array1 = array_flip($array1);
foreach ($array2 as &$value) {
  switch (true) {
    case ( (strpos($value,'H')!==false)&&
           (strpos($value,'O')!==false)  ) :
      $value = str_replace('H',$array1['H']*$array1['O'].'H',$value);
      break;
    case (strpos($value,'H')!==false) :
      $value = str_replace('H',$array1['H'].'H',$value);
      break;
    case (strpos($value,'O')!==false) :
      $value = str_replace('O',$array1['O'].'O',$value);
      break;
  }
}

// $array2 has the new values
print_r($array2);

/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2H4
    [1] => 3O
    [2] => 6H2O
)
*/
```

**edit:**

An alternate method:

```
array_walk($array2,function(&$v) use ($array1) {
  $v = preg_replace_callback('~([HO])(\d+[HO])?~',function($m) use ($array1) {
    return (!empty($m[2]))
      ? (array_search('H',$array1)*array_search('O',$array1).$m[1].$m[2])
      : (array_search($m[1],$array1).$m[1]);  
  },$v);
},$array1);
```

Comment: I am not painting the whole picture just like you said :P 
This is just a part where I got stuck in during programming.